# Prior to placing the meat on the altar in the Temple, was it "kashered"?

Tags: beis-hamikdash, korban, kashering-kosherization, salt

Perhaps, I may be overlooking something trivial, here.

Store-bought meat is salted and soaked to drain the blood, prior to it being packaged and sold to the consumer.

Was something like this done in the *Bet Hamikdash*? I know that many of the animals were slaughtered next to the altar, and the blood was sprinkled on the sides of the altar. But, then, what happened to the meat itself? Was it soaked and salted in a separate area prior to being placed on the altar? Did the Cohen who offered the sacrifice do this, or was this job given to someone else? Were there *mashigichim* or people supervising the process?

Comment: Why would it need to be kashered?

Comment: Meat is salted to remove blood, which we Jews are forbidden to consume. Why should Hashem be forbidden to "consume" blood?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any meat that was burned on the altar was dipped in salt and then put straight on the fire. It was unrelated to the laws of kashering, as we also put straight blood on the altar!

For instance Rambam Laws of Korban Procedures 6:4

> כשמנתח אברי העולה, מוליכין את כל הנתחים לכבש, ומולחין אותן שם.  ואחר כך מעלין כל האברים לראש המזבח, ומסיר גיד הנשה בראש המזבח, ומשליכו על גבי הדשן שבאמצע המזבח; וזורק כל האברים על האש
>
> An all-burnt offering: take apart the limbs, carry them to the ramp, apply salt to them there; then take all the limbs up to the top of the altar, remove the sciatic nerve while on top of the altar and throw it aside, then throw all the limbs onto the fire.

Similarly for an all-burnt sin offering that's a dove (above 6:21):

> וסופגו במלח, וזורקו על גבי האישים
>
> Make it absorb some salt and then throw it onto the fire!

Any meat that a person could then eat would be handed to them, and it was their responsibility to soak-and-salt it (or in some cases, roast it) to remove the blood -- just as everyone until the 1950s (or later) bought salt-it-yourself meat at any kosher butcher shop.

Answer (score 1):

Meat that is grilled directly on a fire does not need to be soaked and salted.  This is particularly useful information for those with restrictions on salt intake as they can still eat meat without worrying about the salt.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question. Did you mean this as a comment?

Comment: @DoubleAA It answers the question by stating that since the meat was going to be grilled on an open flame (the mizbe'ach) it did not require kashering.

Comment: Well that's a wrong answer then. -1

Comment: @DoubleAA How is it a wrong answer?  The question was whether the meat on the altar had to be kashered beforehand and my answer was that it does not.  Seems straightforward to me.

Comment: What you wrote has nothing to do with the Mizbeach. That's why it's wrong. "Irrelevant" may have been a better term. Indeed, meat wasn't kashered before being thown up there, and indeed, meat roasted over fire doesn't need to be salted. But I don't see what those have to do with each other.

Comment: @DoubleAA I am at a loss to undestand you.  The questioner knows that meat has to be kashered by soaking and salting before it can be eaten and the questioner wondered if this rule also applied to the sacrifices.  I pointed out something the questioner perhaps did not know which is that kashering was not required if the meat was going to be grilled on an open fire.  And since sacrifices are grilled on the open fire of the altar kashering was not necessary.  I could have just answered "no" but I was kind enough to give background to my answer.  Elementary logic!

Comment: Background? If by that you mean "irrelevant other material" then yes you gave 'background'. I don't know what "elementary logic" you refer to. All I see is a fallacious argument (non-sequitur) with true premises (you can kasher meat by grilling) and a true conclusion (meat wasn't salted before being put on the Mizbeach).

Comment: To summarize - it is true that meat grilled on an open fire does not need to be salted. I know this, myself, which is exactly why I asked this question. Rules of koshering for personal use may be different than the regulations for altar meat. Your answer needs to relate these two.